# How to set up an user just for JBoss CLI

Tags: jboss7.x, wildfly

I'd need to know if it's possible to setup a management user for the JBoss (AS7 and WildFly) which is valid just for the CLI (and not for the Web console).
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't since the CLI and the Web Console use the same API. Since also both may do the same stuff I don't see what you are trying to achieve.